# Gridview sorted but the select button references the wrong row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, detailsview, commandfield

In my GridView I set AllowSorting="true" and obviuously the view gets sorted upon the column clicked. After this event, the select button besides each row references the row displayed before the sorting event and not the actual one.

A method to reference not the index but the data-key when I click the selcet button?

Comment: See my GridView demo here: https://www.vanderwaal.eu/mini-projecten/gridview-edit-and-update-demo. You can download the source on github for a full working example of a GridVIew edit demo with sorting .

Answer (score 0):

Sorting and a regular asp.net button dropped into the gridview should work just fine.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" AllowSorting="True"
    OnSorting="GHotels_Sorting"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"   SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" 
                    Text="Edit" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdEdit_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, code to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim cmdSQL As New _
        SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GHotels.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And the sort event:

```
Protected Sub GHotels_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs)

    Dim cmdSQL As New _
        SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY {e.SortExpression}")
    GHotels.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

That works just fine.

So, now the above edit button with a simple regular button, and a simple regular button click.

When I click on that button, I have this code:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim pkID = GHotels.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Debug.Print($"Row index click is = {gRow.RowIndex}")
    Debug.Print($"Database PK id is = {pkID}")
    MyEditHotelC.MyPk = pkID
    MyEditHotelC.LoadData()

    ' lets call the js routine to pop our hidden edit div
    Dim strJava As String = "PopEdit('" & btn.ClientID & "')"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "PopEditKey", strJava, True)

End Sub
```

The above correctly outputs the row index, and also correctly outputs the database PK id (hidden in datakeys).

So, I get/see this:

[image]

And the debug.prints show this:

```
Row index click is = 1
Database PK id is = 5
```

So, the simple plain standard button click shows the correct row index, and the PK value via datakeys. Note the use of "namingContainer". This picks up the row you clicked on, and thus lets you dispense with all of the gridview row event mumbo jumbo - which you don't need.